# Sort by with a returned value from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm building a data table and in one column I calculate a value in backing bean, when I try to sort the column the data table turns blank.

```html
<p:dataTable id="tableCargas" styleClass="tableCargas" style="width: 105.5%;" value="#{dashboardBean.listaCargasDM}" var="carga" allowUnsorting="true" sortBy="#{carga.dataEntradaPortaria}" sortMode="single">
    <p:column headerText="Num. nota" style="width: 10%;" styleClass="headerListaCargaDashboard" >
        <h:outputText value="#{dashboardBean.retornaNrNota()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Peso" style="width: 10%;" styleClass="headerListaCargaDashboard" sortBy="#{dashboardBean.retornarPesoCarga()}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{dashboardBean.retornarPesoCarga()}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

These are the columns that I'm having the problem.

Comment: Any errors in your log? And please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: i dont get any error in the console

Comment: Web server / application log, not your browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: no errors in the application log

Comment: Please add a [mcve]